# How can I use an inner div to drag it's outer parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I would like to be able to move an outer div by dragging a specific inner div. Only that inner div should be able move the outer div.

I have attempted to use Jquery's `draggable()` method on the out div but this lets the user move the outer div by clicking and dragging anywhere inside the outer div, which prevent's a user highlighting some text for copying.

I have setup a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/final60/3dp05hoq/2/).

How can I make the outer div only draggable when clicking and dragging on a specific inner div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [**`handle`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) option

> **handle**
> If specified, restricts dragging from starting unless the mousedown occurs on the specified element(s). Only elements that descend from the draggable element are permitted.

```
$("#outer").draggable({
    handle: "#inner"
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xp8v10uw/)